# Hash each line of a Textfile with md5, write it to another File

Tags: bash

How can i write each line of that source.csv in a file. Source look`s like this:

```
Mail1@test.com
Mail2@test.com
Mail3@test.com
```

I want to have this in a file - but only the md5 of every string in line from above.

hashed.csv should look like that, in the end - after opening.

```
2d8c986e36035c262131c06e1579b430
da5a21d0bc55368a719957918d4b3992
2de6b5d122434085d83ff45e8131bba6
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please show the bash code you wrote and explain why it does not behave as you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

>hashed.csv

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s" "$line" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >>hashed.csv
done < source.csv
```

- `printf` is used since `echo` would add a `\n` after the line.
- `awk` is used to remove the   `-` that `md5sum` adds after each checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Miller `mlr` is very fast at doing this on large files.

`mlr --ifs newline --ocsv --headerless-csv-output put '$1 = md5($1);' source.csv > hashed.csv`

- `--ifs newline` is to use the whole line as the input field separator.
- `--ocsv` is to output the result as a CSV file.
- `--headerless-csv-output` is optional but will get the result requested (no CSV header).
- `put '$1 = md5($1);'` will replace the first column (the whole line in this case) with the result of the md5 function.

You can also use a different hashing algorithm quite easily (e.g. sha256):

`mlr --ifs newline --ocsv --headerless-csv-output put '$1 = sha256($1);' source.csv > hashed.csv`